# File reading problem

Tags: java

I am trying to read a file in java. The following is the code.

```
    String str = ".\\SomeFileName";

    File file = new File(str);

    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file.getPath());
```

A FileNotFoundException is thrown in last line. Can some one help?

Comment: Where is the file and from where you are invoking this code ?

Comment: First it was in a local C directory, I thought some problems might be there, so i put in the current directory.

Comment: Also, did you try using a forward slash (or in this case, no dot-slash at all)?

Comment: i did try ./ also didnt help, one more update when i inspect the file object in eclipse, it shows the absolute path as "/./SomeFileName"... but the Path shows right...

Comment: Dont know from where the extra / is coming ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to determine your current working directory.  You can figure out you current working directory with this:

```
String curDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a file in two ways; either absolute, eg

```
String fileName1 = "c:\temp\myfile.txt";  \\For Windows
String fileName2 = "/home/qwerky/myfile.txt";  \\For Linux
```

or relative, eg

```
String fileName3 = "myfile.txt";
```

If you are using the relative path, then the path is relative to java's current working directory. You can find this by getting the file "." and priting the absolute path.

```
File cwd = new File(".");
System.out.println("Current working directory is " + cwd.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by giving absolute path...Full directory path.

```
File file = new File("C:\\abc.txt");
```

and then test this also. str is a string having a file name

```
File file = new File(str);
String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
System.out.println(absolutePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

THe program below is working fine, please first run it by just uncomment the commented statement and comment the InputStreamReader statements

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class FileRead {
public static void main(String args[]){
    try{
         //String str = ".\\SomeFileName";

            File file = new File(".\\file.csv");

           // FileWriter writer=new FileWriter(file);
            //writer.write("it can writer");
            //writer.flush();

            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file.getPath());
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            System.out.println(br.readLine());


    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
}
```

I think YOu have problem in putting the file at correct location